# C++ std::sort with a dynamic array error

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

There are plenty of examples on how to use `std::sort()` with a `std::vector`. For my specific homework assignment, I'm not allowed to use an `std::vector`, so I instead want to use `std::sort()` on a dynamic array of custom objects.

Like so:

```
int numberOfRoads = 100000;
Road* roads = new Road[numberOfRoads];
// Assume the comparator is defined correctly (<- this was the problem)
std::sort(roads, roads + numberOfRoads, SortRoadsComparator);
```

And here is the main compiler error I receive:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\algorithm(3781): error C2664: 'int (const void *,const void *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Road' to 'const void *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I receive this error about 20 times. What exactly is it requiring me to do?

**SortRoadsComparator()**

```
int SortRoadsComparator(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    Road *a = (Road *)v1;
    Road *b = (Road *)v2;

    if (a->Length > b->Length) 
        return 1;

    else if (b->Length > a->Length) 
        return -1;

    else
    {
        // Non-determinism case
        if (a->Length == b->Length)
        {
            if ( (min(a->CityA, a->CityB) < min(b->CityA, b->CityB)) ||
                 (
                      (min(a->CityA, a->CityB) == min(b->CityA, b->CityB)) && max(a->CityA, a->CityB) < max(b->CityA, b->CityB)                                   
                 )
               )
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Not expecting this
        }
    }
}
```

**Solved by billz's comment.**

Comment: could you post SortRoadsComparator?

Comment: Posted. Oh shoot, that's the reason why huh...

Comment: should be: `int SortRoadsComparator(Road const& v1, Road const& v2)`

Comment: Yeah, there's your problem. Why on earth does your comparator take void pointers and cast them?!

Comment: pass by reference... change the comparator to be (const Road &, const Road &)

Comment: Copied that from somewhere I'm afraid @_@

Comment: also `SortRoadsComparator` is too complicated... try to write a simple one which only do simple comparison...

Comment: @billz, what do you mean? Also, thank you for your edit. Problem fixed. I can accept yours as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Note: `std::sort` expects an operator less-than implementation, which returns true if `a < b` for `comparator(a, b)`. You should never return `1` or `-1` from this comparison function.

Comment: heh, I like the "Assume the comparator is defined correctly" when the error clearly sbows that everything with the comparitor is defined incorrectly.

Comment: I should probably remove that, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SortRoadsComparator` function prototype should be:

```
bool SortRoadsComparator(Road const& v1, Road const& v2);
```

You should make sure `SortRoadsComparator` returns weak ordered `Road`.

Comment: What do you mean by a "weak ordered" comparison in the context of my method?

Comment: inside your `SortRoadsComparator` the logic is quite complicated. NO matter under which condition will your `if ( (min(a->CityA, a->CityB) < min(b->CityA, b->CityB)) ||
                 (
                      (min(a->CityA, a->CityB) == min(b->CityA, b->CityB)) && max(a->CityA, a->CityB) < max(b->CityA, b->CityB)` work correctly?

Comment: That should be fine because I copied it from my assignment's instructions :). I guess it's intentionally complicated.

Answer (score 3):

It requires you to pass proper comparator into std::sort. If you read std::sort [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) you can see that it requires following signature:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

and:

> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type RandomIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them.

So in your case dereferenced "iterator" roads has type Road& and function could be something like:

```
bool cmp( const Road &a, const Road &b );
```

PS Looks like you are porting qsort code into C++. Though suggestion to make signature to:

```
int cmp( const Road &a, const Road &b );
```

will compile, it is logically incorrect and would hide the fact that you need to change returned values in your function and slightly change the logic. In current implementation std::sort will most probably crash, but definatelly will not sort your sequence the way you expect it to.

Comment: It's crashing! Segmentation fault. Looks like this has to do with the strict weak-ordering people are talking about? Yes, you're right about the `qsort()`, I was porting.

Comment: Not sure about strict weak-ordering thing, but there is no more segmentation fault after changing the return type to `bool`.

Comment: qsort expects function to return int which means: -1 left object is less, 0 they are equal, and 1 left is greater. std::sort expects boolean which means if left object is less. When you have int in your comparator it implicitly converted to boolean, as any non zero is true your existing comparator works wrong. So basically you need to change it to return true when it returned -1 before and false otherwise.